# Build Error on react-native-navigation first time

Tags: react-native

I have tried to build a react-native app using react-native-navigation. I've went through all the setup stages, but when I try and run the app, I get the following error:

** BUILD FAILED **

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /www/MyProject/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/ReactNativeControllers.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeControllers.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RCCNavigationController.o RCCNavigationController.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Any idea what can be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I thought i was the only one getting this error bro.
After upgrading to react-native 0.31 today, react-native-navigation was having problems. It was working just fine before.
Adding runtime header wouldn't solve the problem. It would let the build go through successfully but the build crashed on me in runtime.

I'm currently considering rebuilding scene transition entirely using react-native-router-flux.